# Converting source code directory into ARFF (WEKA)

Tags: weka

Currently, i am working on a project using WEKA. Being naive and newbie in it, there are many things which i am not familair with. In my last project I used text files as a classification using WEKA. I applied the TextDirectoryLoader convertor to convert a directory containing text files as mentioned on this URL [Text categorization with WEKA](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA). Now I want to use the same stretagy for converting a directory containing source code (instead of text). For example, I have a Jedit source file containing Java source code. I am trying to convert it to ARFF file so that i can apply classifiers or other functions present in WEKA on that ARFF file for data mining purposes. I have also tried a test file given on following URL [ARFF files from Text Collections](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+files+from+Text+Collections). I believe i can use the same file as an example to convert source code files. However, I do not know what attributes should I define in a FastVector? and What format should the data be in (String or numeric). And what other sections should an ARFF file may have?

As in the example the authors have defined following attributes

```
FastVector atts = new FastVector(2);
atts.addElement(new Attribute("filename", (FastVector) null));
atts.addElement(new Attribute("contents", (FastVector) null));
```

I have tried to find some examples on Google but no success.

1. Could anyone here suggests me any solution or alternate to solve the above said problem? (Example code will be highly appreciated).
2. Or atleast could give me a short example which convertes a source code directory into an ARFF file. (If it is possible).
3. If not possible what could be the possible reason
4. Any alternate solution (except WEKA) where I can use the same set of functions on a source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, what is your goal? Do you want to classify the source code files, or find the files which are contains any bug, or what?
As I imagine, you want to extract features from each source file, and represent it with an instance. Then you can apply any machine learning based algorithm. 
Here, you can find a java example, how can you construct an arff file from java:
https://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file
But, you have to define your task specific features and extract it from each source code files.

Comment: Yes i want to classify source code (java files) residing in multiple packages.

Comment: You only need to extract your features from sorce codes. Than you can apply a ML algorithm.

Comment: How to extract features？